# How to keep alive a thread until its function is complete in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, file, download

I am new to multithreading, wrote a code in python where the function creates pop an element from the list and then download it, I am using threads to download multiple files. The problem is that the thread dies and code ends before the download is entirely complete.(downloads incomplete files):

This is the code for threading (download function is running fine, only threading have issues):

```
for i in range(0, 6):
    time.sleep(10)
    name = list.pop(0)
    _thread.start_new_thread(func_download,
                             (name, bucket_name, list, repo_name))
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: show how you are defining your custom method, `start_new_thread`

Answer (score 2):

If this is real-world task, avoid manual thread handling as much as possible.

For your particular case, [`ThreadPoolExecutor.map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) does exactly what you'll need.

In case you need more granular control – take a look at [queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), this is way better synchronization element.

Answer (score 1):

Your main thread has to wait for the other threads to finish. That is not hard to do. You use the `join()` method for that.

```
threads=[] #list to keep an eye on the threads

for i in range(0, 6):
    time.sleep(10)
    name = list.pop(0)
    thread=_thread.start_new_thread(func_download,
                             (name, bucket_name, list, repo_name))
    threads.append(thread)#add thread to the list


for thread in threads:
     #only move on when this thread finished
     thread.join()
#only when all threads finished you will get here
```

Now the programm should only continue after all threads finished.

Comment: thanks for the answer, when I made the changes, I got an error "module '_thread' has no attribute 'join'" although, I have used "import threading" module in the beginning of code

Comment: @DarcyM sorry. Had an error in there. fixed it. _thread.start_new_thread returns an identifier to the thread and you have to add that identifier to the list

Comment: this is not about the identifier, we cannot use thread.join() with _thread, but can use it with "threading"

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what was required :

````
```   for i in range(0, 5):
        time.sleep(5)
        name = list.pop(0)
        print("This is threading") # this print was testing purposes
        thread = threading.Thread(target=function_name,
                                  args=(name, bucket_name, list, repo_name))
        print(thread)
        print("Now starting")
        thread.start()
        print("Waiting")
        thread.join()
    time.sleep(5)```
````

Basically to use join() we will use "threading.Thread" instead of "_thread.start_new_thread"